# Laravel : Call to a member function move() on string

Tags: laravel

I am trying to convert a base64 into png using explode() function, and then pass the file to the "uploads" folder, but it's not working. My Code are :

In my laravel controller :

```
public function verify(Request $request){

    $img = $request->image;
    $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $img);
    $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
    $image_type = $image_type_aux[1];

    $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
    $fileName = uniqid() . '.png';
     
    $request->image->move(public_path('uploads'), $image_base64);
    return redirect('verification');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = 'data:image/png;base64,AAAFBfj42Pj4';

list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);

file_put_contents('/tmp/image.png', $data);
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I done it other way though, but your suggestion to use file_put_contents() was the key